# How to run "stylelint --fix" with husky and lint-staged without blocking the commit

Tags: githooks, pre-commit-hook, stylelint, husky, lint-staged

I'm using husky and lint-staged to run "stylelint --fix" on my sass files with this configuration

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
        "post-commit": "git update-index --again"
    }
},
"lint-staged": {
    "resources/sass/*.scss": [
        "stylelint --fix",
        "git add"
    ]
}
```

and PhpStorm blocks my commit telling me this:

`` Commit failed with error, 0 file committed, 4 files failed to commit: test lintstaged husky > pre-commit (node v12.18.4) ⚠ Some of your tasks use `git add` command. Please remove it from the config since all modifications made by tasks will be automatically added to the git commit index. [STARTED] Preparing... [SUCCESS] Preparing... [STARTED] Running tasks... [STARTED] Running tasks for resources/sass/*.scss [STARTED] stylelint --fix [FAILED] stylelint --fix [FAILED] [FAILED] stylelint --fix [FAILED] [SUCCESS] Running tasks... [STARTED] Applying modifications... [SKIPPED] Skipped because of errors from tasks. [STARTED] Reverting to original state because of errors... [SUCCESS] Reverting to original state because of errors... [STARTED] Cleaning up... [SUCCESS] Cleaning up... ✖ stylelint --fix: resources/sass/_custom.scss 614:1 ✖ Unexpected duplicate selector "body", first used at line 116 no-duplicate-selectors 974:11 ✖ Unexpected unknown type selector "readonly" selector-type-no-unknown 988:1 ✖ Unexpected duplicate selector "body", first used at line 116 no-duplicate-selectors 1313:1 ✖ Unexpected duplicate selector ".btn.clear", first used at line 418 no-duplicate-selectors husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass) ``

I read on the documentation that using the command "--no-verify" it skips "stylelint --fix", but I'd like to run "stylelint --fix" to fix the errors stylelint can fix and to skip the prevent commit.

In other words, I'd like to fix the errors that can be fixed automatically and to commit even if there are some warnings from stylelint.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I found a trick to solve it. When stylelint it's triggered by the flow I described and it finds errors in the code, it exits with error code 2.
https://stylelint.io/user-guide/usage/cli

To prevent exiting, one can set from error to warning the severity of whole stylelint or a single rule.
https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. I also add `--verbose` flags in int-staged command to make sure it print warning message.
https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#command-line-flags